# What's wrong with my PyQt animation?

Tags: animation, pyqt, pyqt5

So I've got a pair of buttons, one with a label, the other with a "delete" icon. The delete button will eventually delete some files, but right now I'm playing with the UI. The buttons are in a GridLayout with a spacer between them. I figure if I shrink the size of the button with the label, it'll "compress" as the spacer enlarges to fill the space. At least that's how it works in Qt Designer.

My button size definition is very simple:

```
ui.labelbutton.setMaximumSize(QSize(315, 50))
```

So I figure the animation should be relatively simple as well. I followed the format of another answer I found here, and I've got this:

```
def anim(self):
    animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'maximumSize')
    animation.setDuration(3000)
    animation.startValue(QSize(315, 50))
    animation.endValue(QSize(10, 50))
    animation.start()

    self.animation = animation
```

I pass it one of the label buttons (after extracting it from the layout - it's dynamically built). And I get an error:

```
animation.startValue(QSize(315, 50))
TypeError: startValue(self): too many arguments
```

According to all the examples and documentation I can find, that should be correct - a QSize is really just one argument, isn't it?

Anyone have a guess at how I can add some pointless eye candy to my application? Thanks.

Comment: What documentation did you read? Surely it's obvious that you must use `setStartValue/setEndValue`?

Comment: Argh. Autofilled by PyCharm. startValue/endValue are options in the autocomplete function, but those methods belong to QVariantAnimation. My mistake. Thanks for the help.